# jQuery fadeIn bug with drop shadow in IE 8?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have an image that has a semi transparent drop shadow behind it, that I am using as a background image in a div.  I am running into an issue where, when I fade the div in or out the semi-transparent drop shadow appears black until the fade completes.  When I do this in FireFox it works fine, I have only been able to reproduce the error using Internet Explorer 8.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/pVQER/2/

Does anyone know why this would happen?  Can anyone suggest a work around or fix?

**UPDATE:**

In my real world example, this div is on top of another background image with a gradient, so I don't think that setting the background color will work.

Comment: I'm having the same black shadow problem... mine is even worse because the element has rounded corners but the shadow is square.  _"IE just sucks"_ is my explanation.  _"Remove the drop shadow in IE"_ is my solution.

Comment: I have also run into the same problem and was not able to find a fix for the issue.  I had to resort to show/hide instead of fading.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to IE8's transparent fade problem is to wrap a div element around the element with the background, set its background color, and fade the wrapper element instead.

**HTML**:

```
<div id = 'bgWrap'><div id="bg">test the background</div></div><br/>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
#bg
{
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/GlEyl.png');   
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid;
    padding:5px;
}

#bgWrap {
     dispaly: none;
    background: #fff;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
      $('#bgWrap').fadeToggle('slow');              
});
```

**Edit**

You can try setting the wrapper div's background as a 1x1 transparent GIF/PNG, which should get rid of your black background problem as well as let the underlying background gradient show through.

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer.  While this works in my fiddle, my real world example has this div on top of another element that has a gradient background, so setting the background color will not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the change I made to your CSS:

```
    #bg {
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/GlEyl.png) 0 0 #fff;   
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
    }
```

I added #fff in the background property. The idea for this work around is to set the background color to match whatever the background behind it is.

Not a great fix, but works.

[Link to code »](http://jsfiddle.net/pVQER/9/)

Comment: +1, thanks for the answer.  While this works in my fiddle, my real world example has this div on top of another element that has a gradient background, so setting the background color will not work for me.